# Take The HAREC exam in spain in english

Tags: license, europe, ham-radio-deluxe

I am looking to take the HAREC exam but I have a dilema, I currently live in Spain and my Spanish language skills are not that great... I was wondering if I can take the HAREC exam online with a Spanish translator sat next to me or if I can take it in English through one of the Irish test centres even though I live in Spain. Would appreciate any help on this subject.